# How to access the single data in a json array?

Tags: json, react-native

The json data is in the below pattern. And the Json data is coming from backend and getting through api and storing in a state variable.

```
this.state = {
jsonData = [
    {
        "address": "xyz",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "id": "12334",
        "name": "abc"
    }
]
}
```

how can I access address value from a state variable.

I have tried accessing the data using

```
this.state.jsonData.address
```

How can I access single value in this case?

Comment: better asking simple questions... please study array and objects in javascript.
try this reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your state like below:

```
this.state = {

   jsonData : [
        {
            "address": "xyz",
            "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
            "id": "12334",
            "name": "abc"
        }
    ]
    }
```

for accessing value try below:

```
this.state.jsonData[0].address
```

Comment: Hey, how can I update the state of individual value in the same array which I mentioned above? @Brijesh Shiroya

Answer (score 1):

First understant what you are trying to access?

you are trying to access array prop inside state, so you can not directly access like object.

so you need to specifiy the index like this -

```
// if you want to access array you need to access via index
this.state.jsonData[index].propname
```

Comment: Hey, how can I update the state of individual value in the same array which I mentioned above? @sathish kumar

Comment: try this to update -> this.state.jsonDate[index] = YourNewObjToUpdate

Answer (score 1):

your object is an array of json objects so to access one of them you must give index.

```
this.state.jsonData[0].address
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the array `[ ]` in the json, and also replace the `=` with `:` as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    jsonData : 
      {
        "address": "xyz",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "id": "12334",
        "name": "abc"
      }      
    }
}
```

and then you can refer it as `this.state.jsonData.address`